# 18.04 Bionic - Cannot print on HP Deskjet 2135

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

So I upgraded to bionic a couple of days ago and can no longer print. Things I've tried

1. Reinstalled cups
2. Tried printer-driver-hpcups as well as printer-driver-hpijs.
3. Eliminated hardware/printer issues by running win10 on a vm and am able to print.

With printer-driver-hpcups:

1. When I try to print test page, I either get

   1. 'Sending to printer' and there is no activity OR
   2. 'Color Manager: no profiles specified in ppd'
   3. There's nothing significant in `/var/log/cups/error_log` AFAICS

With `printer-driver-hpijs`

1. bionic installs 3.17.10 - with this, I get `File \"/usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip-hplip\" not available: No such file or directory`
2. I downloaded the tar.gz from hplip sourceforge site and placed the foomatic-rip-hplip in the folder along with executable rights and root ownership.
3. THe error changes slightly to:

`D [25/Oct/2018:20:05:09 +0530] [Job 133] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip-hplip (PID 20820)
D [25/Oct/2018:20:05:09 +0530] [Job 133] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/hp (PID 20821)
D [25/Oct/2018:20:05:09 +0530] [Job 133] PID 20820 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip-hplip) stopped with status 113 (Permission denied)
D [25/Oct/2018:20:05:09 +0530] [Job 133] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [25/Oct/2018:20:05:09 +0530] [Job 133] execv failed: Permission denied
D [25/Oct/2018:20:05:09 +0530] [Job 133] PDF template file doesn\'t have form. It\'s okay.`

Anyone have any HP inkjet printer working with 18.04? Can someone help?
Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE** - I got the hpcups running

1. First ran `hp-check -r` which reported (among other things)

`PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-2130.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-2130.ppd ppd file`

2. Based on that I did a `chmod a+r /etc/cups/ppd/DeskJet-2130.ppd` and after that the printer prints the test page.
3. What is surprising though is that the group of the file is `lp` - and the cups processes are also running as `lp` so it doesn't make sense. Also, the perms are reset on their own. Do I need to make my  user part of the `lp` group?

Answer (score 0):

for

> bionic installs 3.17.10 - with this, I get File \"/usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip-hplip\" not available: No such file or directory

is tracked by https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=907900
There is a workaround on the page above by editing the ppd file directly.

> editing '/etc/cups/ppd/HP_DeskJet_3630_series.ppd' and replacing "foomatic-rip-hplip" with "foomatic-rip" did work (after restarting the cups service), as you suggested.
>   So it looks like those lines are erroneous in the sid package.

Of course, the ppd file you have will depend on the printer model you have.